# electronic fax (sending) services

Tags: fax, efax

I'm looking for a service to send faxes. I'd prefer a **non-subscription** system - I'd rather pay a few bucks each time I need to fax something (once every six months or so!) than a monthly fee and not use it most months.

Anyone had good experiences?

**edit:** A note that I found Phaxio (https://www.phaxio.com/) which has a lovely API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like [FaxIt Nice](https://www.faxitnice.com/), which allows you to do pay as you go style faxing with a variety of different options ($5.99 for one off faxes).

[Trustfax](https://www.trustfax.com/) offers more traditional plans, as does [efax](http://efax.com).

Answer (score 2):

I'm sending faxes via **[gotfreefax](http://www.gotfreefax.com/)** (limited to US destinations) and **[freeFax](http://www.freefax.com/)**, an ad-sponsored free online fax sending service.

I'm using **[Faxaway](http://www.faxaway.com/)** to receive faxes (sign-up is free, you only pay for sending). You'll get a real fax number that you can give to anyone who wants to send a fax to you. When that fax number receives an inbound fax, Faxaway answers the call, saves the fax as a TIF image, and forwards it on to your email address.

Comment: your link for faxaway is one to gotfreefax, just FYI