# How to send fax from windows7?

Tags: windows-7, fax

How to send fax from windows7? Any Suggestion.. I am using outlook 2007 i want to send a mail as fax.. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you installed Fax Devices at Control Panel >> Printers and Faxes ,first ? if so, you can simply print an email by choosing Fax Devices at Outlook > File > Print . hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a box.net account
enable eFax

upload your file to box.net

you can then fax any file on box.net for free

reference:
http://www.mymoneyblog.com/archives/2009/12/boxnet-free-fax-review-100-free-outgoing-fax-pages-month.html

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up an analog phone modem to your computer to send faxes (most analog modems can also fax). However, this means extra hardware, plus you need an analog phone line.

So usually an online service will be more practical. See this question:

[electronic fax (sending) services](https://superuser.com/questions/88571/electronic-fax-sending-services)